# Crystal Report convert to PDF (Error The logon to the database failed. ((0x8004100f)))

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

In my application I have some code to convert to PDF. In debug mode all is good and working but when I test it on then server I keep getting the logon to the database failed. I have no idea why I get the error becase the login and password are 100% ok.

tried 2 ways for the server of sending the report

```
SetCrystalReportFilePath(Server.MapPath("~/MemberPages/Report.rpt"))
SetPdfDestinationFilePath(Server.MapPath("~/MemberPages/Report_" & Report & ".pdf"))
SetRecordSelectionFormula("{Report.Report_id} =" & ID)
Transfer()



SetCrystalReportFilePath("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Werkbon.rpt")
SetPdfDestinationFilePath("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Werkbon_" & werkbonnr & ".pdf")
SetRecordSelectionFormula("{werkbon.werkbon_id} =" & werkbonnr)
Transfer()

Dim ConInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
Dim oRDoc As New ReportDocument
Dim expo As New ExportOptions
Dim sRecSelFormula As String
Dim oDfDopt As New DiskFileDestinationOptions
Dim strCrystalReportFilePath As String
Dim strPdfFileDestinationPath As String

Public Function SetCrystalReportFilePath(ByVal CrystalReportFileNameFullPath As String)
    strCrystalReportFilePath = CrystalReportFileNameFullPath
End Function

Public Function SetPdfDestinationFilePath(ByVal pdfFileNameFullPath As String)
    strPdfFileDestinationPath = pdfFileNameFullPath
End Function

Public Function SetRecordSelectionFormula(ByVal recSelFormula As String)
    sRecSelFormula = recSelFormula
End Function

Public Function Transfer()
    oRDoc.Load(strCrystalReportFilePath)
    oRDoc.RecordSelectionFormula = sRecSelFormula
    oDfDopt.DiskFileName = strPdfFileDestinationPath
    expo = oRDoc.ExportOptions
    expo.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
    expo.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
    expo.DestinationOptions = oDfDopt
    oRDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("databasename", "password")
    oRDoc.Export()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal is very particular when swapping in and out connection information (especially with sub-reports if you have any).  It's always been a sore spot that they haven't really made any better over the years.  I have a blog entry I've shared that has extension methods I created (in VB.Net) to easily load and swap in new connections (typically I use ADO for the connection in the report).  The extension methods can be found in this link (and below is an example of how to use them, ignore the System.Diagnostics line if you're using this from ASP.NET).  Hope this helps.

http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=487

```
    Using rd As New ReportDocument
        rd.Load("C:\Temp\CrystalReports\InternalAccountReport.rpt")
        rd.ApplyNewServer("serverName or DSN", "databaseUsername", "databasePassword")
        rd.ApplyParameters("AccountNumber=038PQRX922;", True)
        rd.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "c:\temp\test.pdf")
        rd.Close()
    End Using

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\temp\test.pdf")
```

Comment: Tanx for the reply i will let you now if i can get it to work